# How to instanciate indexed block in pyomo abstract model with parameters indexed with an index foreign from the block?

Tags: pyomo

I am writing an extensive problem in pyomo in which i need to activate and deactivate assets in projects. I think the easiest way to model this is to write an abstract model and then put each asset into a block. Then every time a model would be instanciated it would be possible to activate only certain type of blocks and a certain number of each blocks (ie 3 block wind turbine). Therefore the block will be indexed. Inside these blocks I define parameters that are time dependent but the time will be a shared index between all so it won't be local set but a general set.

Here is a short example of the typical situation I am running into:

```
import pyomo.environ as pm

model=pm.AbstractModel()

model.A=pm.Set()
model.T=pm.Set(ordered=True) #the set of Time

def Ablock(b,g):
    b.A_param=pm.Param(model.T)
model.A_block=pm.Block(model.A,rule=Ablock)

Amodel_dict = \
    {None : dict(
        A = {None:[1,2,3]},
        T = {None:[4,12,23]},
        A_block = { 1: dict(A_param = { 4:3, 12:4, 23:5}), 
                    2: dict(A_param = { 4:5, 12:6, 23:7}), 
                    3: dict(A_param = { 4:8, 12:9, 23:10})}
                )
    }

instance=model.create_instance(data=Amodel_dict)
```

This gives the error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to set value for param=A_block[1].A_param, index=4, value=3.
    source error message="Index '4' is not valid for indexed component 'A_block[1].A_param'"
```

Intuitively i feel it is wrong to call for `model.T` inside the function `Ablock` as it is not supposed to know what it refers to but if i give it as an argument of the function, it modifies the block creation to block indexed on time as well. Do you have any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution that was quite simple but very practical. Instead of calling `model.T` one should navigate in the hierarchical structure by using the functions `model()` or `parent_block()`.

A solution for my problem is to call:

`b.model().T` or `b.parent_block().T`